# unable to find a record in my db although it is present in my db

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using findOne() method to search through my db using the following code

```
    app.get("/articles/:articleId", (req, res) => {
       Article.findOne({ _id: req.params.articleId}, (err, foundArticle) => {
            if(foundArticle) {
                res.send(foundArticle);
            } else {
                res.send("No article found");
            }
        });
    });
```

using the following URL in postman

> http://localhost:3000/articles/626e950e4fb74295f5139b78

and passing the object id for the following record in the DB

```
    {  
        "_id": "626e950e4fb74295f5139b78",  
        "title": "Albert Einstein",  
        "content": "Did you know that sleep is good for your brain? Einstein sure did, he slept for 10 hours a day!",  
        "__v": 0
    }
```

but My find one code returns **no article found**, even though the article is present

collection modal

```
    const articleSchema =  {
        title: String,
        content: String
    };
    
    const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);
```

Comment: I would check your `req.params.articleId` value to ensure it is actually passing in a valid article ID. Additionally, you may be throwing an error, so put a breakpoint on your `if (foundArticle)` code, and see if the `err` object has information.

Comment: Looking at the manual at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne it says when searching by id, you should use findById instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying different solution I finally got to solve the issue by
adding a _id: string in the schema solves the issue

```
    const articleSchema =  {
        _id: String,
        title: String,
        content: String
    };
```

rest of the code will remain the same